# ANT how can I make a new dir with the current date as part of the dir name

Tags: deployment

I want to use the ANT based deployment tool.
With ANT how can I make a new dir with the current date as part of the dir name?

Comment: What kind of directory? Local on your machine or something inside Salesforce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
<target name="account">
  <tstamp>
    <format property="tstamped-file-name" pattern="ddMMMyyhhmmss" locale="nl,NL"/>
  </tstamp>

    <if>
        <available file="data/accounts.csv" property="account.present"/>
        <then>
             <sfdc object="AccountUpsertProcess"/>
             <move todir="status-history/Account${tstamped-file-name}">
                <fileset dir="data">
                    <include name="accounts.csv"/>
                </fileset>
                <fileset dir="status">
                    <include name="AccountUpsertProcess*.csv"/>
                </fileset>
             </move>
        </then>
        <else>
           <echo message="No account file"/>
        </else>
    </if>

</target>
```